# How to find different files in UNIX based on . extension?

Tags: shell, files, filenames

How to find different files in UNIX based extension. Lets say suppose if I have 100 files for each vamsi.log-vamsi100.log, krishna.txt-krishna100.txt, super.csv..., rajat.jpeg..., kiran.xml-kiran100.xml and etc. My requirement is if I give command it'd only give how many different patterns do I have in one folder. It should also deliver one for each extension. How can I achieve this?

`ls -ltr` gives all files. But I need to know how many different type of files there in one folder?

Comment: What is your criterion for matching a "type"? You have three different numbering schemes in your examples (extension followed by dot followed by number, extension followed by number, and filename followed by number followed by dot followed by the extension.

Comment: it should give result like .txt, .log, .csv one for each pattern

Comment: For answers ending in `| uniq -c` it might be interesting to look at the results ordered by count of files with that extension: `| uniq -c | sort -n`

Answer (score 3):

Bash command: `for i in *; do echo "${i##*.}"; done | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -u -t. -k3 | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`: find all normal files in current directory
- `sort -u -t. -k3`: sort the output on `3` filed with `.` as a field separator and print only first of equal lines
- `wc -l`: count the lines

---

**Edit**

If you are using `zsh` shell then you can run

```
echo ${(u)$(echo *(:e))} | wc -w
```

The result is probably better then in `find` case - at least multi-dot files are properly taken into account, if you are also interested in files which names start from `.` then

```
echo ${(u)$(echo {.,}*(:e))} | wc -w
```

Comment: Just a remark: this assumes that you don't have other dots in file names as for example `a.b.c.txt`.

Comment: I'd like to offer substitute `sort` and `wc` by `grep -o "\..\{,4\}$" | uniq -c`

Comment: Well, one can replace sort and wc with `rev | cut -d. -f1 | rev | uniq -c` or even use `find`s exec option to directly execute `awk -F"." '{print $NF}'` and then pipe results to `uniq -c`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `ls *.extension` should do the trick :)

To count them, you can use `ls *.extension -1 | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 -a | ls *.foo | wc -l
```

Where foo is your extension.

Comment: perhaps an explanation of the piping of the two `ls` commands would be useful here?

Answer (score 1):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq -c`

`awk` being used to grab whatever comes after the last `.` (the "extension")

`sort` to get all occurrences of each "extension" grouped together

`uniq -c` to show the number of duplicates of each row/extension.

Answer (score 0):

Some script with bash-builtins and assotiative array

```
declare -A F_TYPE
unset F_TYPE
while IFS=" ," read b c d f
do
  n="$b${c:+ $c}${d:+ $d}"
  F_TYPE[$n]=$[${F_TYPE[$n]}+1]
done < <(file -b *)
for i in "${!F_TYPE[@]}"
do
  echo "$i = ${F_TYPE[$i]}"
done
echo "Totally ${#F_TYPE[@]} types"
```